# Add text on the circle created by the leaflet L.circle() function

Tags: leaflet

I use the following function to create a series of circles around a clicked point on a leaflet map. I would like to label each circle by placing the distance (r or radius) on the circle line itself. But I can't find any option or function to do this. Can someone tell me how?

```
function circleKoords(e) {

   var myJSON = JSON.stringify(e.latlng); 
   //alert("myJSON "+myJSON); 
   // myJSON {"lat":39.257778150283364,"lng":-94.41925048828126}
   // myJSON {"lat":39.39587712612034,"lng":-93.54583740234376}

   var LatLng = e.latlng;
   var lat = e.latlng["lat"]; //alert(lat);  // 39.172658670429946
   var lng = e.latlng["lng"]; //lert(lng);

   var i;
   var r = 1609.34;  // in meters = 1 mile, 4,828.03 meters in 3 miles
   //https://jsfiddle.net/3u09g2mf/2/   
   //https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/240169/leaflet-onclick-add-remove-circles
   var group1 = L.featureGroup(); // Allows us to group the circles for easy removal

   var circleOptions = {
       color: 'blue',
       fillColor: '#69e',
       fillOpacity: 0.1
   }  

   var milesbetween = 0; var numberofrings = 0;  

   var milesbetween = prompt("How many miles between circles?");
        if (milesbetween <= 0) {milesbetween = 1;}
   var numberofrings = prompt("How many circles do you want to see?");
        if (numberofrings <= 0) {numberofrings = 5;}


   // The actual circles are created here at the var Cname =
   for (i=0 ; i < numberofrings; i++ ) {
       var Cname = 'circle'+i; //alert(Cname);  // circle0, circle1, circle2, etc.
       r = (r * i) + r; r=r*milesbetween;
        //alert(lat+", "+lng);  // lat and lng of clicked point.
        //alert('r= '+r); // r= 1609.34, r= 3218.68, r= 4828.0199999999995, etc. up to the number of rings
       var Cname = L.circle([lat, lng], r, circleOptions);
            Cname.addTo(group1); 
          //  r = 1609.34;  // reset r so r calculation above works for each 1 mile step 
          map.addLayer(group1);
        r = 1609.34;
    }

    alert("All "+numberofrings+" rings are "+milesbetween+" mile apart.");

    // This part allows us to delete the circles by simply clicking anywhere in the circles.
    group1.on('click', function() {
        if(map.hasLayer(group1)) {map.removeLayer(group1);}
        //else {map.addLayer(group1);}
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the L.GeometryUtil library:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet-geometryutil@0.9.1/src/leaflet.geometryutil.min.js"></script>
```

Update your circle loop to:

```
// The actual circles are created here at the var Cname =
   for (i=0 ; i < numberofrings; i++ ) {
       var Cname = 'circle'+i; //alert(Cname);  // circle0, circle1, circle2, etc.
       r = (r * i) + r; r=r*milesbetween;
        //alert(lat+", "+lng);  // lat and lng of clicked point.
        //alert('r= '+r); // r= 1609.34, r= 3218.68, r= 4828.0199999999995, etc. up to the number of rings
       var Cname = L.circle([lat, lng], r, circleOptions);
            Cname.addTo(group1); 
          mymap.addLayer(group1);
         //180° from top
         var p_c = L.GeometryUtil.destination(L.latLng([lat, lng]),180,r);
         var icon = L.divIcon({ className: 'dist-marker', html: r.toFixed(0)+';iles', iconSize: [null, 16] });
             var marker = L.marker(p_c, { title: r.toFixed(0)+'Miles', icon: icon});
         marker.addTo(mymap);
          //  r = 1609.34;  // reset r so r calculation above works for each 1 mile step 
        r = 1609.34;
    }
```

CSS:

```
.dist-marker {
    margin-left: -8px !important;
    font-size: 9px;
    border: 1px solid #777;
    border-radius: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #000;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 0 3px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/falkedesign/3aukgm7t/

Answer (score 2):

Can you try putting this after "var Cname = L.circle([lat, lng], r, circleOptions);"?  This attempts to add a label to the same coordinates with the text "radius" followed by the computed radius value.

```
var label = L.marker([lat, lng], {
   icon: L.divIcon({
     className: 'label',
     html: `radius ${r}`,
     iconSize: [0, 0]
    })
  });
  label.addTo(group1);
```